# DialogPreference set title of Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, listener, preference

I have a DialogPreference. I would like to set its Dialog title (setTitle()), but it is not working.

My code:

```
public class RestoreDefaultApperanceDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    Dialog dialog;

    public RestoreDefaultApperanceDialogPreference(Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        dialog = getDialog();
        //dialog.setTitle("Restore default colors?"); //<- NOT WORKING!
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public RestoreDefaultApperanceDialogPreference(Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

XML FILE (Preference category):

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Appearance settings">
        <com.example.dictionary.ColorSelectPreference
            android:key="onlineRecognitionColor"
            android:title="Online recognision results color" 
            android:summary="Customize color of online recognition results."
        />
        <com.example.dictionary.ColorSelectPreference
            android:key="offlineRecognitionColor"
            android:title="Offline recognition results color" 
            android:summary="Customize color of offline recognition results."
        />
        <com.example.dictionary.RestoreDefaultApperanceDialogPreference
            android:key="restoreDefaultApperance"
            android:title="Restore default apperance" 
            android:summary="Choose this option to restore default apperance settings." 
        />
 </PreferenceCategory>
```

**How can I setTitle to this Dialog**

Comment: Have you tried this:

    public void setDialogTitle (CharSequence dialogTitle)

Sets the title of the dialog. This will be shown on subsequent dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setDialogTitle()` and override `onDialogClosed()` to capture the button clicks and perform your actions.

```
public RestoreDefaultApperanceDialogPreference(Context context,
        AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setDialogTitle("Restore default colors?"); // <- this should work
}


@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

    if (positiveResult) {
        // OK button is pressed
    } else {
        // Cancel button is pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: When I call setTitle on the Preference, it will change both dialog title and preference title. I want to have i.e. "Click to reset settings" on preference and "Are you sure?" on Dialog.